# I need help in estimates lme models

Tags: convergence, longitudinal, random-effects

I'm analyzing two models of class LME for longitudinal data (observations in two times), but
this message appears `Error in lme.formula(y ~ x, random = ~1 | id, data = data_long) : nlminb problem, convergence error code = 1 message = false convergence (8)`. This error appears on two models, what is it?

My outcome is continuous and normal errors. Can I use another estimator or some argument to correct this error? My predictor in dichotomous.

Output R:

```
mod7 <- lme(y~x,random=~1|id, data=data_long)
# output:
# Error in lme.formula(y ~ x, random = ~1 | id, data = data_long) :
# nlminb problem, convergence error code = 1 message = false convergence (8)

summary(mod7) 
# output:
# Error in lme.formula(y ~ x, random = ~1 | id, data = data_long) :
# nlminb problem, convergence error code = 1 message = false convergence (8) 
# Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : erro na avaliação do argumento 'object' na seleção do método para a função
# 'summary': 'objeto 'mod7' não encontrado'
```

I need estimates a `lme` model for hormone by sleep duration (short X normal), but the model no converge.

Comment: Can you please give a toy dataset that reproduces the error?

Comment: did you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75109603/convergence-error-code-1-message-false-convergence-8